# Why did everyone laugh hysterically at Howard and Myron in the toy store?

Tags: plot-explanation, jingle-all-the-way

In *Jingle All the Way*, Howard tells a toy store employee that he's trying to find a Turbo Man Doll and then Myron says the same. Why do the employees and everyone in the store laugh at them hysterically?

Answer (score 6):

The employee explains it pretty clearly a minute or so after everyone stops laughing:

> "Where have you guys been?  Turbo Man is only *the hottest selling Christmas toy ever*, duh!"

The Turbo Man doll is **the toy** every kid wants for Christmas that year.  The simple idea that there would be any stores with a Turbo Man doll left in stock, and you could just waltz in and buy it, is laughable.

As an aside, the IRL toy craze for Christmas 1996 was centered around *[Tickle-Me Elmo](http://www.cbc.ca/player/play/1102522435571).*  The outrageous demand for this, and other toys before it, I'm sure, served as the basis for the movie's plot.

Comment: And certain video game consoles ever since, where they usually end up on ebay at twice the MSRP (Manufacturers Suggested Retail Price).

Comment: Indeed, nowadays it doesn't even need to be Christmas time.